# tableview as a intelligence in iphone not working

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield, resignfirstresponder

I have a `textfield` and a `tableview`. User may select `textfield` data from `tableview` or any other data.but after entering user own data my `tableview` must disappear.how can i achieve this.if i use resign first responder `did select row`method is not working in `tableview`.

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
      {

        UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        txtcity.text = selectedCell.textLabel.text;


      }
     -(void)hideKeyboard  //this is my gesture recogniser method
      {

         autocompletetableview.hidden=true;//if i didn't use this statement it enter into didselectrow method
      }
     - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {


   autocompleteTableView.hidden=YES;
    if( textField == txtcity)
   {


    autocompleteTableView.hidden = NO;

     NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
         substring = [substring stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
     [self searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:substring];// this method loads data    into my tableview



      return YES;
     }


   }

   (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
   {
    if([txtcity.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
    autocompleteTableView.hidden=YES;

    return YES;
     }
    else
    autocompleteTableView.hidden=NO;
   }

  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger) section {


   return arr2.count;
 }

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    static NSString *AutoCompleteRowIdentifier = @"AutoCompleteRowIdentifier";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault        reuseIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier] autorelease];
}

     cell.textLabel.text = [[arr2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Name"];
    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
     cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=0;

   return cell;
}
```

if i use like this if i select row  it doesn't enter into did select row at index path method. help me

i am not getting where i have to use resignfirstresponder

Comment: eventhough user didn't select the row of tableview if i clicked outside of text field tableview should disappear

Comment: got my point shall i elobrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resignFirstResponder` is used to dismiss the first responder ( keyboard in the case of `UITextField`). If you want the tableview to disappear set the `hidden` property to true or remove the tableview from the view hierarchy.

i.e;

```
[tableView setHidden:YES]
```

or

```
[tableView removeFromSuperview];
```

**UPDATE:**
If using gesture recognizer for checking on the tap on parent view, you can do the following so that the gesture method is not fired unnecessarily.

I'm assuming you are writing all this code in the view controller for the whole thing.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGe = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
tapGe.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapGe.delegate =self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGe]
```

Then implement the following method in the view controller (Make it conform to `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol):

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
  If(touch.view==self.view){
     return YES; //If its the main view accept the touch
  }else{
     return NO; //Otherwise(say tableview) don't consume the touch.
  }
}
```

Comment: where can i write this statement.shall use in tap gesture recogniser method

Comment: if i use in this method if i select the row in tableview textfield not taking the  data

Comment: It's upto you. Write this whenever you want the tableview to be removed. IF you want tableview to disappear when tapped outside you can use the gesture recognizer. no problem

Comment: are you hiding the tableview after setting the text or before?

Comment: ya i set the text some times as one of row and some times other

Comment: actually it shouldn't matter. I just tried out the code, it works. There should be something else wrong with the code.

Comment: when iam editing my text field tableview is appearing.even thoguh  table view is appearing i want to set the textfield data some other which is not in the tableview

Comment: One more thing, rephrase your question in a more clear way so that others can also help you with it.

Comment: log your textfield. Check if you are getting the right object. also log the cell's text.

Comment: i edited my question.i think now u got my actual problem. help me

Comment: there is no problem in cells text

Comment: Is the issue that your table view is disappearing before you can select the row. Or you can select the row but the method is not being called?

Comment: the method is not being called if i select row.

Comment: but the method is called if didn't use tap gesture recgnoiser method

Comment: Sorry, don't find any reason for that to happen. It shouldn't happen as the code to hide the table view is not even executed before you select the row. Anyway instead of using a gesture recognizer, put `autocompletetableview.hidden = YES` in the `didSelectRow..` method.

Comment: Then i'm out of ideas or don't really understand what the problem is as the same code is working perfectly for me. :|

Comment: actually my tableview data is coming from the service.it changes depends on the data on the textfield.shall i post these methods also

Comment: my gesture recogniser method is in view did load

Comment: i will clarify u clearly. while editing my textfield if i clicked outside rather than clicking on the table view my view should disappear.remember while editing textfield i want to call gesture recogniser method.

Comment: Still I dont see any reason why you are not able to select the table row. Sorry. You could create a small dummy project to test out just this functionality and if its still not working, you can share it with me and i'll help as I can.

Comment: One more thing. In your updated code , in the textfield end editing method if there is some value you are keeping the tableview not hidden and if there is no value you are keeping it hidden. Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: you can check it by tracing.if i select row in tableview firstly it is enter into the gesture method and then textfield did end editing and then it enterd into the did select row at index path.so if i use hidden statement in gesture method so my tableview hide before didselect row.thats why my text field not copied in this case.but at where i can use this one still confusion

Comment: Alright I can help you with that. Will edit the answer in a minute. :)

Comment: one more problem in my gesture method i used [testScroll endEditing:YES];
after this statement it is enter into endediting method and then coming back to gesture method after that didselect

Comment: That should be the right flow. See if the updated answer helps you.

Comment: always guest recogniser returns no actually i added gesture recogniser to the scroll view.bcoz i added scroll to my view. due to this is there any problem

Comment: thankyou verymuch its awesome.iam very happy. i have struggled from last week.once again thanks.

Comment: i have some problem. i have some text fields below to the textfield they become uneditable

Answer (score 0):

I think It's useful to you.I have used custom cell and I have give my working code here.

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [mainDetaileArray count];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 115;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProductMerchantCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (UIView *view in views)
        {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {
                cell = (ProductMerchantCell*)view;
                //cell.img=@"date.png";

            }
        }
    }

    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;



        txtfield = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(104, 36, 58, 31)];
        txtfield.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:56.0f/255.0f green:84.0f/255.0f blue:135.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        txtfield.delegate = self;
        txtfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
        txtfield.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        indexVal = indexPath.row;

        [txtfield setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
        txtfield.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        txtfield.text = [quantity_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   // NSLog(@" txtfield.text %@", txtfield.text);
        [txtfield setTag:indexPath.row];

        [txtfield setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords];


        NSString *total_str_price1=[[mainDetaileArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"total_product_price"];

        cell.availbl_pro_lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total : %@%@",add_currnce_str,total_str_price1];

        cell.title_pro_lbl.text=[[mainDetaileArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"product_title"];

        str_price=[[mainDetaileArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"product_price"];

        cell.price_Pro_lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Price : %@%@",add_currnce_str,str_price];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:txtfield];


    return cell;

   }
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    addtoValue = textField.text;
    [quantity_array replaceObjectAtIndex:textField.tag withObject:textField.text];


   // NSLog(@"quantity_array %@",quantity_array);
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [cell.Quantity_txt resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [cell.Quantity_txt resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: may be a simple question may i know what is diff. between cell and custom cell

Comment: all the textfields and tableview i added to scrollview